# X509Cerificate check if is issued from some CA

Tags: java, certificate

I have a problem, because I can not find a way to check if issuer of some certificate is CA with some digital certificate.

Is there any way that I have CA digital certificate and I have some user certificate and I want to check if CA issued that digital certificate for that user in Java.

Thanks a lot.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Path..\\user_certificate.cer");
         CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
         X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);

//in same way I can get CA certificate and I want to check
//if certificateIssuer is CA with that digitalSigniture
```

Comment: A certificate issued by a CA is signed by that CA; to check if a child EE cert is signed by a parent CA cert, use [java.security.cert.Certificate.verify(PublicKey)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify(java.security.PublicKey)) or one of its or `X509Certificate`'s overloads, with the publickey from the parent cert. Note however that establishing the cert _was_ issued by a given CA does not mean it is valid or should be trusted _now_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is abstract method, so which class (method) override this verify method.. I am sure that I do not have to override it ..

Comment: Both `java.security.cert.Certificate` and `(same).X509Certificate` are abstract, and the object returned from `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()` is actually a subclass (within an available cryptoprovider, which can vary) that implements all required methods, but you just use it as if it were `X509Certificate`. In particular you can call any of the `verify` overloads as you choose.